# Cannot assign a value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'String!'

Tags: swift

I am trying to call images but getting error "Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'String!'" in the line "vc.sentData2 = image".

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView"){
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            let Title = names[indexPath.row] as String
            vc.sentData1 = Title

            let url = NSURL(string: images[indexPath.row])
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            vc.sentData2 = image
        }
    }
}
```

I would be thankful for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly obviously, in your definition of `DetailViewController` you've declared `sentData2` as a `String!`  And, in this case you're trying to assign a `UIImage?` (the result of `UIImage(data:)` is always a `UIImage?` since there may be no valid image) to a `String!`.

So, change

```
var sentData2: String!
```

in DetailViewController to

```
var sentData2: UIImage?
```